# Cannot mount LVM partition after restoring LVM metadata

Tags: centos, mount, partition, lvm

I have resized two LVM partition (/var and /home) and somehow resize process went wrong. After reboot system wasn't able to mount /var and /home. I have used RIPLinux to check if I can mount those partitions from there but not.

In a next step I went and restored LVM metadata from /etc/lvm/archives before partition resizing following steps from [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html).

> lvs -a -o +devices

shows correct partitions - I was able to mount /var but not /home - that one returns an error message:

> *** Error for /dev/mapper/vg_pc1-home: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg_pc1-home,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

Executing

> dmesg | tail

gave

> bad geometry: block count 44533760 exceeds size of device (39290880
>   blocks)

Is there anything what I can do to get /home back to work?

PS.

I have left run testdisk over the weekend to see what is going on. Found bunch of issues on /sda4 (device related to /vg_pc1-home). Will take a look later what are all of them.

Comment: Did you shrink an lvm partition without first shrinking the filesystem?

Comment: What type of filesystem? Did you make a backup of your data before resizing?

Comment: @teppic I think so I didn't add -r with a command

Comment: @bdowning It is ext4 and yes - I have a backup :)

Comment: What partition type did you use? 83/8e, other?